# srcElement not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, events

I've been putting together a lightweight event utility for cross-browser event handling, but have come across a rather high hurdle I can't quite jump over. It's concerning the srcElement property in IE9, which just isn't working for me!

Currently, my utility looks something like this (the srcElement is the 3rd code block):

```
var bonsallNS = new Object();

bonsallNS.events = {
addEvent: function (node, type, func) {
    if (typeof attachEvent != "undefined") {
        node.attachEvent("on" + type, func);
    } else {

        node.addEventListener(type, func, false);
    }
},
removeEvent: function (node, type, func) {
    if (typeof detachEvent != "undefined") {
        node.detachEvent("on" + type, func);
    } else {

        node.removeEventListener(type, func, false);
    }
},
target: function (e) {
    if (typeof srcElement != "undefined") {
        return window.event.srcElement;
    } else {
        return e.target;
    }
},
preventD: function (e) {
    if (typeof srcElement != "undefined") {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
}
```

Now, using the following test script below works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but returns the evtTarget to be undefined in IE when I try to alert it. I have NO idea why, so any help would be greatly appreciated! See below code:

```
var gClick = document.getElementById("clickme");
var gCount = 0;

function mssg(e){

var evtTarget = bonsallNS.events.target(e);
alert("it worked, target: " + evtTarget);
gCount++
if (gCount > 2){
    bonsallNS.events.removeEvent(gClick, "click", mssg);
}
}

function setUp(){
bonsallNS.events.addEvent(gClick, "click", mssg);
}

bonsallNS.events.addEvent(window, "load", setUp);
```

Like I say, everything else works except for the event source in IE!!

Comment: IE version? event model differs on IE<=8, so this information is crucial.

Comment: Shouldn't `if (typeof srcElement != "undefined") {` be `if (typeof e.srcElement === "undefined") {`?

Comment: Or rather, `typeof window.event.srcElement !== "undefined"` - which works, thanks! Schoolboy error.

Comment: @Funny: Actually neither mine nor your is completely correct... will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `srcElement` will always be `undefined` unless it's defined in a higher scope. But it will never refer to `event.srcElement`.

You can solve this problem in two ways: Either check whether `e` or `e.srcElement` are not defined, or whether `window.event` and `window.event.srcElement` are defined.

```
if (typeof e === "undefined" || typeof e.srcElement === "undefined") {
// or
if (typeof window.event !== "undefined" && 
    typeof window.event.srcElement !== "undefined") {
```

You can also shorten the whole function to:

```
target: function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement;
}
```